# SAP Crystal Report Runtime (13.0.33) fails with code c00000fd

Tags: crystal-reports

SAP Crystal Report Runtime 13.0.33 is generating a c00000fd exception in a NET Framework 4.7.2 winforms app.

The application has two accesses: Backoffice and Frontoffice. Both of them are in the same process/application.

If a try to open a report using Crystal Report from the Backoffice it works perfectly.
If a try to open a report using Crystal Report from the Frontoffice I get a c00000fd exception.
If a try to open a report first from Backoffice and the from the Frontoffice it works fine.

Using WinDbg I notice the exception occurs in this precise moment:

```
ModLoad: 66f00000 66f3c000   C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\querybuilder.dll
ModLoad: 66ef0000 66ef7000   C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\querybuilder_res_en.dll

(d98.f80): Unknown exception - code c0000090 (first chance)
```

- Last error is repeated almost 50 times
- And Finally

```
(d98.f80): Stack overflow - code c00000fd (first chance)
```

The code I use in the backoffice and the frontoffice are the same. The error occurs with several reports not only one in particular.

I tried reinstalling NET Framework, Crystal Report Runtime, etc. with no success. I think the problem might have been generated by Windows Update because there were no changes to the code and suddenly it began to fail.

Hope someone can help me.

Thans in advance!